# Adding Image views to the horizontal scroll dynamically (through code)

Tags: android, android-studio, horizontalscrollview

I just started working on android a day ago and I'm working on scrolls. I have already made one but I would now like to do the same thing dynamically.

This is the code for my activity_main.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id= "@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:onClick="onTouch">


    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>




<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomlinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#00ffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp">>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/drop"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Drop Zone" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Total"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Success"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Fail"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically I would like to add 10 images from the drawable into the horizontal scroll as image views dynamically. Any help or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Tried this its stretching the image over the whole screen

`LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            String uri = "drawable/a" + i;
            // int imageResource = R.drawable.image1;
            int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setBackgroundResource(imageResource);
            sv.addView(iv);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I'm gonna post the solution hoping that it helps someone else having a similar issue. I originally made 3 horizontal scroll views and the xml for one of them is like this

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The code I wrote to create Image Views inside Linear Layout of horizontal scroll view:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   for (int j=1; j<=10; j++)
    {
        b1=j;
        create_img1("drawable/a"+j, b1);
    }


}

void create_img1(String ss, int ID)
{
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgLayout1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    parms.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);

    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(ss, "id", getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    imageView.setId(ID);
}
```

I made one for multiple scroll views with drag and drop functionality but I filtered it out and if you want to create image views inside scroll views dynamically, this is what you are looking for. Hope this helps someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do like this.

1. Create an xml layout which holds the imageView.

image_item.xml

```
 <ImageView

            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
```

2. Now find the container where want into java file, like this.

   ```
   LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
   ```
3. Now just run a for loop till 10 and add the views at runtime.

   ```
        for(int a = 0 ; a < 10 ; a++)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
           containerLayout.addView(inflatedView);
       }
   ```

Hope this helps, Feel free to discuss if found problem.

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
mHScrollContentView = (ViewGroup) findViewbyId(R.id.linearlayout1);

ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);

ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_2);

ImageView iv3 = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_3);

ImageView iv4 = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_4);

mHScrollContentView.addView(iv1);
mHScrollContentView.addView(iv2);
mHScrollContentView.addView(iv3);
mHScrollContentView.addView(iv4);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html

You might get an answer here!